# Meta question deleted for no known reason in less than 2 days it was asked

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, meta

**Edit - question is deleted by myself after it was reopened**

One of my question (on meta Stack Overflow with feature request) got deleted in less than 2 days it was asked, without warning or notification. Users with 10k+ rep can still access question [here][1] and help me to suggest what was wrong exactly

I tried to evaluate all following reason, but could not find one which could be a good reason for deletion

- extremely off topic
- very low quality
- against policy such us abuse, etc..
- closed question and pending for deletion

url given below (will not work for less than 10k rep, sorry for that )

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376964/metric-suggestion-to-motivate-users-to-upvote-downvote-and-accept-answers

I agree many of the community member disagree with feature ( I wrongly picked unknowingly it exists in past and removed )  and probably they are right but it doesn't mean, such suggestions should be deleted immediately within 2 days and even without sharing a reason.

**Edit - question is deleted by myself after it was reopened**

Comment: Formally, closed questions are subject to deletion (for closed questions that weren't closed as dupl*cates, there is even [an automatic process that does so if certain conditions are met](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/242059)). However, I believe it is almost never necessary to manually delete Meta questions. That fate should be reserved for those which are blatantly off-topic, hopeless rants, or flamewar arenas; your question doesn't fall in any of those cases.

Comment: There is about 78% chance that you'd rage-delete linked question anyway... So I see not much of a problem in deleting post that does not bring anything new and essentially endup being traditional discussion about commenting on downvotes... At least you have time to review all comments and re-read existing information on topics you brought up instead of wasting your and others time on repeating same arguments in comments...

Comment: Mentioned question is undeleted, thanks to all who have voted to undelete question. Please let me know if you find anything wrong with question or comments, I will try to correct it.

Comment: 40 downvotes so far.  Setting a record is not easy, 233 more needed.  At some point you hopefully realize there is no point to it and the original moderation was actually useful.  You might have to hurry that along, it is about to get deleted again.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, just deleted that..

Comment: @Alexei if only you could edit your comment to say 100%....

Answer (score 14):

After a question has been closed (as duplicate in this case), it can be voted to be deleted. If three users vote to delete, the question is deleted. This is what happened here. The reason why three users felt the need to delete your question can only be speculated about, but here I suspect people got fed up with seeing the question bumped again and again by your continuous edits, while simultaneously feeling that you’re entirely unreceptive to any counter arguments.

Comment: 1) unreceptive to any counter arguments - These are incorporated in question with answers 2) multiple edits, yes it is being done to improve contents and include more contents 3) regarding duplicate, I have updated my reason it is not, but looks like it is not sufficient, so after some time,I have share screen shots with more details that how it is not duplicate at all

Comment: You don’t need to convince *me* of anything here, I didn’t vote on that question. I’m just *telling* you what (likely) happened. And, well… you're really continuing the same pattern here as in that question. People *tell* you what’s wrong, and all you have is counter arguments.